existence of triangulations of manifolds
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold.
Let $K$ be  a simplicial complex.
Let ${\rm  sd}(K)$  be  the  sub-division of $K$.
Suppose there exists a simplicial sub-complex $K_1$ of ${\rm  sd}(K)$ such that $K_1$  is  a  triangulation of $M$.
Question. Whether or not can we obtain there exists a simplicial sub-complex $K_2$ of $K$ such  that $K_2$  is  a  triangulation of $M$?  How about the special case if $M$ is compact and without boundary?
Are there any references?

In general, the answer is no. For an example, suppose that $K$ is the boundary of the four-simplex.  Thus $K$ is a triangulation of the three-sphere.  Now every closed connected oriented surface of genus $g$, denoted $M_g$, embeds in some subdivision of $K$.  However, as $g$ grows, more and more subdivisions are needed. In particular, only the two-sphere, $M_g$, embeds in (the two-skeleton of) $K$.

It is similar but even a more trivial example is to take $K$ as $2$-simplex. The disjoint union of (at least two) $S^1$s appears as a subcomplex of a  subdivision of $K$ but not as a subcomplex of $K$.
